# HttpClient Get Request to a weird URL

Tags: c#, httpclient, html-agility-pack

I need to send the HTTP Request to the URL of online Data Management Systems. I am using the following codes:

```
         public async Task StartCrawl()
    {
        var url = "http://pww.comopsdms.healthcare.philips.com/livelink/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objId=3890195&objAction=browse&sort=name&viewType=1";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
      }
```

Here, it works with all the other URL links but does not work with the above link. HttpClient sends the request but receives nothing. And flow does not go to the next line.

The link only works inside the company network.

Comment: Are you running this from inside the company network?

Comment: put it in a try-catch (and even remove async for test) and see what exception you get, I have seen lots of exceptions like , 404, 500 that has nothing to do with your code and you can only catch exceptions and possibly skip it.

Comment: yes I am running it inside the company where I can access the link through browser

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I did not get your point. Did you try my codes.